# MySQL start not as service

Tags: mysql, configuration

im a little bit new with configuring MySQL. My problem is that we need to run MySQL on a computer where MySQL is already installed as Service. We dont have the access to root. Since the MySQL Service is important for an application which is running on the computer we cant just remove/reinstall it. Maybe the application will be used again. So i tried to install xampp and try to start the MySQL not as service but it seems to be impossible.

Is it possible to start the MySQL not as Service? The following appears whenever i start the XAMPP Control Panel:

```
[mysql]     MySQL Service detected with wrong path
[mysql]     Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
[mysql]     Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
[mysql]     Found Path: "C:\private\private\bin\mysqld-nt" --defaults-file="C:\private\private\my.ini" MySQL
[mysql]     Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

So i have been trying to disable the Service and then manually start

```
mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
```

Afterwards the process is running, and i get the following in the console:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
2015-02-11 10:52:53 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-02-11 10:52:53 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

Then i cant connect to mysql:
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>

```
mysql -u root
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

Btw im using Windows 8 64bit if that matters.

Another Question: Does the root password stay the same as in the service? I mean MySQL and MySQL Service is installed in a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest i feel really stupid now.

Editing the ini value from key_buffer to key_buffer_size worked. It shouldnt say Warning ...