# Is it possible to run MySQL not as a service

Tags: mysql, windows

I need to get WAMP stack running on a Windows 7 computer with no admin access. 
I managed to get Apache running not as a service and I'm trying to get MySQL working now. I've tried SQLite, but it crashes on the Drupal install.

Is there a way to run MySQL *not* as a service?

I found [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045494/running-starting-mysql-without-installation-on-windows) for getting it running without installation, but get the error:

```
mysqld: Could not create or access the registry key needed for the MySQL
application to log to the Windows EventLog. Run the application with sufficient 
privileges once to create the key, add the key manually, or turn off logging
for that application
```

I'm aware there is [another self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451409/mysql-start-not-as-service) on here, but the solution isn't actually what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there is already a MySQL server running on your machine. Try the following steps:

1. Type `Services` in search box
2. Find MySQL service and right click it to stop it.
3. Try to connect your server in XAMPP or wampp.